# Is thread still running when the process in "Disk Sleep"?

Tags: c, linux, sleep, disk

When a process go into the special kind of sleep, known as "D" or "Disk Sleep" in Linux, is its child thread still running normally ? So that the thread could tell me the process is in "Disk Sleep" state.

[about the "D" state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475683/linux-process-states)

BTW: Sorry for my poor English and thank you all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Linux threads are defined as "tasks".

Each task is an individual execution unit within a process. They all have their individual task id `tid` - related to process ids (`pid`s).

Each process comes with one main task when it starts and that "main" task identifies the process and indeed the process id `pid` is the task id `tid` of the main task.

The process state in terms of execution resembles that of the main task including the status `R`, `D`, `S`...

So if your process is marked as `D` (Disk sleep) it just means that the main task is in disk sleep. All other tasks (threads) could be doing anything else.

Check `/proc/[pid]/task/[tid]/stat` for individual task states.

Also `ps -eLf` to display ps entries for tasks.

Try this code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void * thread_sleep() {
    long long int i = -1;
    while (i--);
    exit(0);
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, thread_sleep, NULL);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Run it and do

```
cat /proc/$PID/stat
cat /proc/$PID/task/*/stat
```

You will notice that the process has status `S` (waiting for terminal input) as does the first task (same `tid` as the process `pid`) while the other thread is `R`. If you set `i` to something smaller it will actually finish at some point.