# What's the most elegant and safe way to kill a non-responding process in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, linux

I have a C# program that compiles and executes a C++ program. Sometimes, if there are infinite loops during runtime, the process gets into a linux D mode which means that it is not responding to anything because it's waiting for an internal event (I/O).

To write to the C++ program I have redirected the Input and Output stream accordingly.

```
if (input.Trim () != "") {
        proc.StandardInput.WriteLine (input);
}
try{
    output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd ();
}

catch{
    output = "Runtime > 500ms .";
}
```

A timer checks if the process lasts longer than 500 ms and tries to dispose it if so. Otherwise, it [kills](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it.

```
timer.Elapsed += delegate {
                    try{
                        try{
                            proc.StandardOutput.Close();
                            proc.StandardInput.Close();
                        }catch{}
                        try{
                            proc.Kill();
                            proc.Dispose();
                        }catch{}
                            timer.Enabled = false;
                            Log.Warn("A process took longer than expected. Streams and objects were disposed.");
                        }
                        catch(Exception e){Log.ErrorTrace("Timer " + e.ToString());}

                    };
```

Although this method works most of the time, when the server is filled with requests for running programs with infinite runtime orphan processes start to appear and eat up resources.

[image: top]

The program runs as root hence the possibility of lacking permissions is null.

**Is this the right way to dispose Processes which imply running non-responding tasks on a linux machine?**

Please note:

- that the requests are made via sockets, therefore timing is crucial.
- that killing the processes manually via pid will fail ([see D mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475683/linux-process-states))

Comment: Out of curiosity, from which aspects do you (want to) consider it "safe"?

Comment: Safe = to dispose all processes safely; to avoid orphans (and implicitly high system load)