# blocking a process in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, io

I'm confused about what happens when a process is being blocked waiting for an event. I didn't find technical documentation about such. (i.e.) like that of the `socket` library when a server is receiving connections from clients with the `accept()` method. If there'd been no pending connections the process is blocked until it receives one. Is there a library that is used for doing this?

Comment: The blocking is happening in the underlying `accept()` system call, i.e. the kernel is blocking the process.

Comment: Yeah, I'm familiar with the general concept, I'm wondering how is it done with some code?

Comment: It's implemented in the kernel of the OS. You can look at the Python source code for the socket module to see the code that invokes [`accept()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8d9bb11d8fcbf10cc9b1eb0a647bcf3658a4e3dd/Modules/socketmodule.c#L2385). There is no library as such that implements the blocking at Python or C level (assuming cpython). The next step is to read the source code for the kernel of the OS that you are using.

Comment: Such process does not run on CPU. The scheduler selects other process that is "runnable". Related question (or a dup?):  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475683/linux-process-states